# Null pointer exception, taking data form lists and arrays

Tags: java

I've checked everything several time, can't get where I am wrong..

Main class:

```
    try
    {
        File productData = new File("productData.txt");
        Product [] consideredRange = InputFileData
                                          .readProductDataFile(productData);

        ElectronicsEquipmentSupplier management = 
                   new ElectronicsEquipmentSupplier(1, 12, consideredRange);  


        File customerData = new File("CustomerData.txt");
        Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(customerData);

        while(fileScan.hasNext())
            management.addNewCustomer(InputFileData.
                                                readCustomerData(fileScan));       

        management.addNewPurchaseOrder("21/01/12", "PSC-1235", "kD/9767", 50);            

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

InputFileData class works perfectly. I have created an object of ElectronicsEquipmentSupplier with a consideredRange of products. Also added customers to a customersList.

Here is ElectronicsEquipmentSupplier class:

```
    public class ElectronicsEquipmentSupplier 
    {
         private int currentMonth;
         private int currentYear;
         private Product [] productRange;
         private CustomerDetailsList customersList;
         private PurchaseOrderList currentYearList;
         private PurchaseOrderList lastYearList;


    public ElectronicsEquipmentSupplier(int currentMonth, int currentYear, Product [] range)
    {
         this.currentMonth = currentMonth;
         this.currentYear = currentYear;
         productRange = new Product[range.length];
         customersList = new CustomerDetailsList();
         currentYearList = new PurchaseOrderList();
         lastYearList = new PurchaseOrderList();
    }

    public void addNewPurchaseOrder(String dateStr, String customerID, 
         String productCode, int qty) throws IncorrectPurchaseOrderException
    {
    // check for positive order quantity
    if(qty < 1)
        throw new IncorrectPurchaseOrderException("Order quantity must be"
                                                            + " positive!");

    // check for the product code in given range and get that product 
    Product foundProduct = null;

    for(int i = 0; i < productRange.length; i++)
    {   
        if(productRange[i].getProductCode().equals(productCode))
        {   
            foundProduct = productRange[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    if(foundProduct == null)
        throw new IncorrectPurchaseOrderException("Product code is not in"
                                                   + " the product range!");
    try
    {   
        // creating OrderDate object and getting appropriate discount
        OrderDate newDate = new OrderDate(dateStr);
        int discount = customersList.findCustomer(customerID).
                                                          getDiscountRate();

        // creating purchase order and adding it to a list
        PurchaseOrder givenOrder = new PurchaseOrder(newDate, customerID, 
                                               foundProduct, qty, discount);

        currentYearList.addPurchaseOrder(givenOrder);

        // updating the record of purchasing customer
        int priceValue = givenOrder.getFullPriceValue();
        customersList.findCustomer(customerID)
                                        .updateTotalOrdersValue(priceValue);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {   
        throw new IncorrectPurchaseOrderException("The problem is with: "
                                                                + "\n" + e);
    }
}
```

It shows that I've got NullPointerException at:  `if(productRange[i].getProductCode().equals(productCode))`

and in the main class at:

management.addNewPurchaseOrder("21/01/12", "PSC-1235", "kD/9767", 50);

Can't get why, as I have all required info..

Thank you!

Update 1:

Added this to the main method to solve first issue:

```
            for(int i = 0; i < consideredRange.length; i++)
            management.getProductRange()[i] = consideredRange[i];
```

But now the ID of a customer cannot be found... 
That's the method in CustomerDetailsList class, which throws exception:

```
public CustomerDetails findCustomer(String givenID)
                                            throws CustomerNotFoundException
{   
    int i = 0;
    boolean match = false;

    while(!match && i < listOfCustomerDetails.size())
    {
        match = listOfCustomerDetails.get(i).getCustomerID()
                                                           .equals(givenID); 
        i++;
    }

    if(!match)
        throw new CustomerNotFoundException("The provided ID has not been"
                                                                + " found");
    else
        return listOfCustomerDetails.get(i);
}
```

Update 2: updated .findCustomer() as SMA suggested

Comment: Looks like `productRange[i]` would be null. You can't call `getProductCode()` with it.

Comment: Why? I think I initialized the array of product range with a constructor, isn't it?

Comment: Or getProductCode returns null

Comment: You initialized the array itself but not its elements. So they are still `null`.

Comment: getProductCode is a simple accessor method without anything in it

Comment: After your edit: the solution you chose is not clean. Since you have a constructor and you pass an array to initialise it, you should do the member init _in_ the constructor, not outside. For the second pb, what is the exception?

Comment: @Abbé Résina   Yes, I noticed that from your comment! But the excersise I do requires to implement the following in the main methiod... I think, in general, it will not be clear, but it will work this way as well, isn't it?   The exception is: CustomerNotFoundException, which is thrown by findCustomer method

Comment: That's not your question, but the return value from `findCustomer()` won't be good and can throw an `ArrayindexOutOfBoundException`: when you have a match, you should not increment `i` in order to return the found customer.

Comment: @Abbé Résina   Can I avoid it simply with: return listOfCustomerDetails.get(i-1)  ??  Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to initialize product in constructor like

```
productRange = new Product[range.length];
```

And then using it like:

```
if(productRange[i].getProductCode().equals(productCode))
```

Now you allocated space for your array but individual array elements i.e. products are not initialized and hence you get NullPointerException. To resolve the issue, you could do something like:

```
productRange[i] = new Product(..);//and then use it
```

Comment: Thank you! But now I've got another problem with:              int discount = customersList.findCustomer(customerID).
                                                              getDiscountRate();

Comment: It throws curtomerNotFoundException, which means that there is a problem with a customersList... Any idea?

Comment: I dont see which code throws that exception and where you catch it. This should be a followup question, so i would suggest to close this one and open a new one

Comment: loop over your listOfCustomerDetails rather than just checking first element of the list.

Comment: you mean in .findCustomer method?  The is an incremet i++, or it doesn't work this way?

Comment: Move this `boolean match = listOfCustomerDetails.get(i).getCustomerID()
                                                           .equals(givenID); ` in while loop

Comment: updated. Could you please check if it makes sense now? Got another exception though (not with that one)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because productRange[i] has not been initialized.

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor you need to fully initialise the `productRange` array. Right now you are just creating an array of `null` references.

```
 public ElectronicsEquipmentSupplier(int currentMonth, 
                                     int currentYear, 
                                     Product [] range) {
     this.currentMonth = currentMonth;
     this.currentYear = currentYear;
     productRange = new Product[range.length];
     for (int i = 0; i < productRange.length; i++) {
        productRange[i] = range[i];
     }
     customersList = new CustomerDetailsList();
     currentYearList = new PurchaseOrderList();
     lastYearList = new PurchaseOrderList();
 }
```

The above solution build a new array which reference the same objects as the `range` array passed to the constructor.

You may just want to reference the array without any allocation, e.g.

```
 public ElectronicsEquipmentSupplier(int currentMonth, 
                                     int currentYear, 
                                     Product [] range) {
     //...
     productRange = range;
     //...
 }
```

Or do a deep copy of the `range` array, assuming you have either a `Product#clone()` method or a `Product` constructor that takes a `Product` parameter, e.g.

```
 public ElectronicsEquipmentSupplier(int currentMonth, 
                                     int currentYear, 
                                     Product [] range) {
     //...
     productRange = new Product[range.length];
     for (int i = 0; i < productRange.length; i++) {
        productRange[i] = new Product(range[i]);
     }
     //...
 }
```

The choice between these different methods depends on how the `ElectronicsEquipmentSupplier` class is used.